# Transmission script-torrent-done not executing?

Tags: transmission, transmission-daemon

settings.json

```
"script-torrent-done-enabled": true,
"script-torrent-done-filename": "/var/lib/transmission/.config/transmission-daemon/torrent_complete.sh"
```

the owner of the `torrent_complete.sh` - is `transmission`, the `chmod` is `777`, but the script is still not executing, what I am doing wronggg?